# JQuery: почему не удается получить текст в теге, если cdn ссылка на библиотеку рабочая, а библиотека успешно подключается?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Только изучаю JQuery, возникла проблема, не могу банальную вещь сделать, получить из дива своей веб-страницы то, что написано между тегами. Запускаю такой код:

```
<script>
function jQuery($) {
            let form = $("#probe");
            console.log(form);
        }
</script>
```

Он находится под html до закрывающего тега .

библиотеку JQuery подключаю в том же файле вот так:

```
<head>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Чат-программа</title>
</head>
```

Библиотека рабочая, если ссылку в браузере вставить, то отдает информацию. Скрипт ее успешно подключил потому, что при запуске всего этого дела результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как он может быть undefined, когда в самом html на того же файла, где вышеописанный код:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="d" id="probe">fvfvfvfv</div>
            <h3 id="head">Форма сообщений</h3>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `function jQuery($)` Вот это вообще подозрительно выглядит. ВЫ создали функцию, а в качестве параметра $ что передаете?

Comment: `jQuery(function($) { ... });`. Синтаксис такой должен быть

Comment: @SwaD, если убираю $ из скобок, то у меня IDE ругается на $ в let form = $("#probe"); - Unresolved function or method

Comment: Откуда вообще взято это `function jQuery($) {`?

Comment: @rusgeli если делаю так: jQuery(function($) {
            let form = $("#probe");
            console.log(form);
        }); то ругается на jQuery - Unresolved function or method а в консоль при запуске отдает jQuery is not defined
    at (index):49:9

Comment: @u_mulder IDE подсказывает такой вариант.. (PHP Storm у меня)

Comment: @SwaD когда делаю так jQuery(function($) {
            let socket = io.connect();
            let form = $("#probe");
        }); IDE подчеркивает jQuery как undefined function и предлгает создать функцию jQuery, при нажатии выдает шаблон function jQuery($)

Comment: @Valentin, да вообще уберите все эти `jQuery(function($)`, `function jQuery($)` и т.д. Это какая-то муть.

Comment: @humster_spb убрал, все равно норм синтаксис не работает: let form = $("#probe"); console.log(form);

Comment: @Valentin, кеш почистили после изменений? Какие ошибки сейчас выдаёт?

Comment: @humster_spb да, кеш почистил, сервер перезапустил, даже из-под другого браузера попробовал - то же самое...

Comment: @Valentin, тогда могу предположить, что скрипт у Вас по какой-то причине отрабатывает раньше, чем отрисовывается DOM, потому и результат undefined

Comment: логично, попробую найти как изменить это..

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, откуда Вы взяли конструкцию `function jQuery($)`? Было бы любопытно взглянуть на первоисточник.

Всё гораздо проще:

```js
let form = $("#probe"); console.log(form);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="d" id="probe">fvfvfvfv</div>
            <h3 id="head">Форма сообщений</h3>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не срабатывает у меня let form = $("#probe"); console.log(form); Пишет на $ Unresolved function or method, а в консоли ncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):48:20
(anonymous) @ (index):48

Comment: @Valentin, ну здесь же срабатывает (я специально сделал воспроизводимый пример, который можно запустить и посмотреть). Значит, у себя Вы что-то не так подключаете или что-то не то запускаете.

Comment: да, я знаю, что вы правильно сделали, свой вариант я сделал после того, как у меня не пошел код в вашем варианте... Весь вопрос, почему у меня это может не работать... У меня есть сокет сервер на node js, который подключает html, который мы тут рассматриваем вот так: app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
}); если переходишь в браузере на localhost по нужному порту, то он подтягивает index..

Comment: причем, сервер работает нормально, потому что если сделать так function jQuery($) {
    //       let form = $("#probe");
            console.log('skdsdjskdj');
        } то эта skdsdjskdj выводится

Comment: @Valentin, ну всё правильно - потому что дело не в сервере, а в вот этой странной конструкции `function jQuery($)` - она и не даёт корректно работать jQuery. Console.log работает, потому что это чистый js. А `let form = $("#probe")` уже не работает.